# How to resize a small image in sync with the center of a full screen image?

Tags: html, css

[Link to Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-b6z5qu?file=index.html,styles.css)

On my page I have with mutple effect and layers and that image contains a watch, which's dial is always centered in the middle of the image (tried to represent this here with the man on my example image, the man isn't quite centered but I hope you get the idea of it).

Now I want to add hour/minute/second handles to those watch.
These handles should always be the same size as the dial of the original full-screen image.

In other words, in the stackblitz, the handle should always have the same height/width ratio as the man in the picture.

I have no idea how to sync size with an `object-fit: contain/cover/fill`  property.
The only idea I have would be to make the handles also a full screen image with the same height as the watch. Then I could apply the same effect to it. But this makes the image size way too large + since they are supposed to display real-time all the transform operations on them are also more expensive. And most of all it bothers the ... out of me that I cannot figure this out.